# How to deal with “OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error”?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, speech-recognition

I am relatively new to Python. I am trying to create a program to open youtube. Here the user is supposed to say "open youtube" and python should open it in the browser. However, I am continuously getting OS error in the below code. When I tried the same program on my friend's PC, error surprisingly disappeared! But it persisted in my system for some reason. On thorough study, I found the issue is with the line "audio = r.listen(source)", where the code returns an error. Kindly help. ( I have checked my microphone, no issues seem to be there).

```
import pyttsx3 #pip install pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr #pip install speechRecognition
import webbrowser
import os

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
# print(voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def takeCommand():
    #It takes microphone input from the user and returns string output

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 0.5
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")    
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)    
        print("Say that again please...")  
        return "None"
    return query


while True:
    query = takeCommand().lower()

if 'open youtube' in query:
            webbrowser.open("youtube.com") #end of code


I am getting the following error message:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-a53e26f9d26c> in <module>
     32 
     33 while True:
---> 34     query = takeCommand().lower()
     35 
     36 if 'open youtube' in query:

<ipython-input-15-a53e26f9d26c> in takeCommand()
     14 
     15     r = sr.Recognizer()
---> 16     with sr.Microphone() as source:
     17         print("Listening...")
     18         r.pause_threshold = 0.5

c:\users\it\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py in __enter__(self)
    139                     input_device_index=self.device_index, channels=1,
    140                     format=self.format, rate=self.SAMPLE_RATE, frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK,
--> 141                     input=True,  # stream is an input stream
    142                 )
    143             )

c:\users\it\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py in open(self, *args, **kwargs)
    748         """
    749 
--> 750         stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
    751         self._streams.add(stream)
    752         return stream

c:\users\it\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py in __init__(self, PA_manager, rate, channels, format, input, output, input_device_index, output_device_index, frames_per_buffer, start, input_host_api_specific_stream_info, output_host_api_specific_stream_info, stream_callback)
    439 
    440         # calling pa.open returns a stream object
--> 441         self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
    442 
    443         self._input_latency = self._stream.inputLatency

OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error
```

Comment: If you are using Windows 10 then make sure that the inputs aren't blocked in the "microphone privacy" in "settings". Refer to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4468232/windows-10-camera-microphone-and-privacy

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Ahmad. Actually, I have already allowed the use of my microphone so it should not be the case.

Comment: Did you find any answers?